# Entity object : Cloning and Inserting

Tags: database, entity-framework, object, entity, clone

I am trying to clone/copy an entity object and insert it to the DB. I am using Entity Framework.

I found several similar question here and over other forums. Though the exact issue, None of the solution worked for me.

```
Application orginalApp = new Application().GetById(origAppId);
Application clonedApp = orginalApp.Clone<Application>(); //uses DataContractSerializer
DataBaseContext.Current.Detach(orginalApp); // Current is a property which returns Database context which is stored in httpcontext.current.items

clonedApp.EntityKey = null; // tried with and without this

clonedApp.Application_Id = 0; // tried with and without this. This is the primary key
clonedApp.Application_Name += " (clone)";

clonedApp.Create();   //The usual Addobject and SaveChange()
```

This throws the following error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

I tried to check for existance of the object in object state manager.

```
DataBaseContext.Current.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(clonedApp)
```

It give me Null.

*** Though, I couldnt find a solution, got to a workaround for the requirement using reflection.***

Comment: I think that you should at least tell what framework are you using for this, because its unclear.

Comment: ouch. Sorry. The question is edited. I am using Entity framework

Comment: I fixed this by implementing cloning using reflection

Answer (score 0):

This error says that you have the same primary key for your new object as you did for your old one, if you are cloning rows, you will need a new PK for the cloned row